# How to properly use RTK Query with Next js SSR?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, rtk-query

I'm recently learning rtk query and I've been facing the challenge of using this library with SSR mechanism in Next js.

My codes go like below:

blog.tsx (blog page):

```
import Layout from "@components/Templates/Layout"
import BlogsPage from "@components/Templates/BlogsPage"
import store from "@redux/store"
import { blogApi } from "@redux/api/blog"
import { useGetBlogPostsQuery } from "@redux/api/blog"

export default function Blog() {
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useGetBlogPostsQuery();

  return (
    <Layout>
      <BlogsPage
        posts={data.results}
      />
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  store.dispatch(blogApi.endpoints.getBlogPosts.initiate())

  await Promise.all(store.dispatch(blogApi.util.getRunningQueriesThunk()))
  return {
    props: {}
  };
}
```

my store.ts:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { blogApi } from './api/blog';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [blogApi.reducerPath]: blogApi.reducer,
  } as any,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat([
    blogApi.middleware,
  ]),
})

export default store;
```

my blogApi:

```
import { httpClient } from "./httpClient";

const injectedEndpoints = httpClient.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (builder) => ({

        getBlogPosts: builder.query<any, void>({
            query: () => ({
                url: `/blog/post/`,
                method: "GET"
            })
        }),

    })
})

export { injectedEndpoints as blogApi };
export const {
    useGetBlogPostsQuery,
} = injectedEndpoints;
```

and finally my httpClient is:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
import { HYDRATE } from 'next-redux-wrapper'

export const httpClient = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL+'api/v1' }),
  extractRehydrationInfo(action, { reducerPath }) {
    if (action.type === HYDRATE) {
      return action.payload[reducerPath]
    }
  },
  endpoints: () => ({}),
})
```

I think I have done everything correct according to the [official docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/server-side-rendering), plus there are some things missing in docs like "how to exactly retrieve the ssr-fetched data in the page component" since we are not passing any props in Blog component with this method

the final result is, that I'm seeing the request being sent to server on my client-side, and the ssr configuration doesn't seem to be working.

Is there anything I'm missing?